# Handling JIRA dropdown None option while comparing a dataframe column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jira

I am facing an issue while comparing None (default) option in JIRA dropbox fields against a dataframe column.

```
issue.raw['fields'][result]['value'] != df.RESULT.values[0]
```

issue.raw['fields'][result]['value'] is None which is the default value set in the dropbox. For all the JIRAs having None selected as the option in dropbox, am facing this issue.

The error that I see is -

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Please advise how to handle such None options.

Comment: `if issue.raw is not None: ...`

Comment: Thank you, @QuangHoang . But I would be comparing and updating based on Dataframe values I get. Let's say result field in JIRA is None and if RESULT in dataframe is Positive, I would want to update JIRA with Positive. When I make comparison between None and Positive, this error seem to happen. How can i handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` exception happens when you try to access something that's not a List using the bracket notation. (i.e. `obj[1]`).

Knowing that, the error on your code could be caused by:

1. `issue.raw['fields']` is None, therefore `issue.raw['fields'][result]` causes the error.

or

2. `df.RESULT.values` is None and `df.RESULT.values[0]`causes the error.

Assuming your DataFrame `df` is properly structured, the error is comming from option `1` and your code could be fixed with the following validation:

```
if issue.raw['fields'] is None:
    # Create a field List
    # Create a field with a value same as DataFrame's value
elif issue.raw['fields'][result]['value'] != df.RESULT.values[0]:
    # Update field value with DataFrame's value
```

Comment: Thank you @drakmord2. This is what i ended up doing - str('not available' if issue.raw['fields'][result] is None else issue.raw['fields'][result]['value']) != df.RESULT.values[0]. It worked :)